# Cookies not set at the frontend,

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, setcookie

My cookies is being passed from the backend to the frontend and its also available at the Set-Cookie in the headers tab on the console, but with that, the cookies is not appearing at the frontend in the application tab, which logs me out on every reload.

This is My code at the backend: in My App.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary")
const fileupload = require("express-fileupload");
const cors = require('cors')


const errorMiddleWares = require("./middleWares/errors")

// app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3000", credentials: true }));
const corsOptions = {
  origin: true,
  credentials: true,
};
 
app.use(cors(corsOptions));


and in my sendToken module for the cookies:
const sendToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {
    // the user will be the userschema attached in the authusercontrolllers, also the status code too, but the res is from here

    //create jwt token
    const token = user.getJwtToken();

    //to store jwt token in the cookie, we prepare options
    const options = {
        expires: new Date(
            Date.now() + process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRES_TIME * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
        ),
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite:"None",
        secure:true
    }
    res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', `token=${token}`);
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

    res.status(statusCode).cookie("token", token, options).json({
        success: true,
        token,
        user
    })
};
```

Answer (score 3):

When using `httpOnly`, on the frontend javascript cannot access to the cookie. Plus, it can only be send using `https` protocol.

When using `sameSite:"None"`, the `secure` attribute must be set to `true`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#attributes

Those attributes are great for production usage, but on development you must change you approch either by using:

- `https` for localhost, need to generate some insecure key (do not commit them) and allow insecure localhost on Google Chrome `chrome://flags/`
- turn `httpOnly:false`, `sameSite: "Strict"` and `secure:false` if `process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"` (make sure it is set to `production` when deploying to production)

Answer (score 2):

In development/http, use `secure: false`. [Secure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies) being `true` prevents cookies being set in http communications.

I also recommend setting up a `dotenv` (`.env`) configuration for local development and then doing something like

`secure: process.env.INSECURE_COOKIES !== "true"`

and then in your envfile (usually `.env`) putting

`INSECURE_COOKIES=true`